# Pycharm IDE Refactoring /Renaming Error

Tags: python, ide, pycharm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sz4v.png)I just downloaded PyCharm and renamed a project I was working on. I looked up how I would do that, and saw I needed to refactor it, but I didn't know what that meant. Now, my code won't show me errors. I just typed in random letters and no errors appear.

Right after I refactored it, the colouring of the letters changed and the file icon changed from the the python file icon, to a calculator looking thing. How do i change the file name, without this happening.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Open up VCS > Local History > Show History, and revert to the earliest version you did (before you renamed).  Do you still have the same issue?

Comment: Refactoring in Intellij is renaming the file's name most commonly, this means anywhere that file is referenced, needs to be changed to reflect the new naming convention, refactoring should in no instance change the file icon or type from what you are describing.

It would be more beneficial if you were to produce a screenshot of what you are referencing and how/what you actually refactored. Was it a class? a file? the project name itself?

Thanks @Makoto for pointing out this is where this is a comment not a answer

Comment: @makoto Yeah, I reverted it, and now everythings back to normal.

Comment: @ sentinal Its just a file with functions that I'm using for another file. Overall I have just two files. Ill edit my question, and upload a screenshot

Comment: @Sentinel I think it has something to do with the fact that the file was saved as ,py. i saw that it wasnt named properly and decided to change it to .py. I refactored another file that it named correctly, and the same thing doesn't occur.

Comment: @scamander_juan I would just remake the file with a different name and rename everywhere it is referenced in your program. I'm not sure the best practice method to go about fixing an issue like that